# Recommended way to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu

I am newbie to **OpenCV**. What I found (after spending considerable time) on searching how to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 is that there are two ways to do so.

1. `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`
2. Install OpenCV manually. i.e. download source code and build it.

Please suggest, when one should use what ?

**PS:** I will be using OpenCV in **Java** project.

Comment: did you find also from [Official OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)?

Comment: however, you should be ok with custom build unless you need contrib modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have install opencv in my Ubuntu 14.04 via apt-get and using it from last 2 months. **sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev** installs version 2.4 which is sufficient for me till now. So I am happy with this way.